# How to get a tourist visa to Korea?

Tags: japan, tourist-visas, nepali-citizens, korean-air

I’m a Nepali citizen currently living in Japan. Can I get a tourist visa from Japan to Korea? If it’s possible, how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're in Tokyo, go visit the Consulate in Minami-Azabu. If memory serves, preferrably in the morning. Bring your passport, Japanese ID/visa, proof of address, proof of status (employment, student, etc), ID photos. With any luck, you might be able to apply that very day. If not, they'll tell you what you need.